# How to play songs automatically from play list?

Tags: c#

i am currently making windows media player in c#. I want to play songs automatically from my play list.But unfortunately after a lot of try i am still unable.Here is my code :

```
string auto[];
public void AutoPlay(AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer play, ListBox lb)
{
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
auto[i] = lb.SelectedItems.ToString();
play.URL = auto[i];
}
```

Comment: Never worked with AxWindowsMediaPlayer but when I see your code you are overwriting play.URL with every time. If play.url is a array of strings you should append the value to play.url and not overwriting it constantly. You also don't need auto as far as I can see

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you don't actually add links to playlist you just play the last one try this code

```
string auto[];
public void AutoPlay(AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer play, ListBox lb)
{
                var myPlayList =   play.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("MyPlayList");
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    auto[i] = lb.SelectedItems.ToString();
                    play.URL = auto[i];
                    var mediaItem = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(auto[i]);
                     myPlayList.appendItem(mediaItem);
                 }                  
                 play.currentPlaylist = myPlayList;
}
```

Comment: make sure that the file paths are correct and if you get any exception mention what is it

Comment: Is shows me a message box "The file you are attempting to play has no extension."

Comment: what is the file path?

Comment: by mistake i put "auto" instead of "files" ... now corrected...it runs but it gives error when i click on the file (copied in listbox) in play list.

Comment: i don't understand you ,is the answer solves your problem?